# Spring boot endpoint parameter signature, is throwing ambiguous endpoint exception when both parameters are given

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, ambiguous

Due to the way it was engineered in the past, there was one endpoint created for a specific parameter called `foo` in this case.

However the requirement meant that the endpoint could be used either with `foo` or a new parameter called `bobby`.

After trying to consolidate into one endpoint, the refactor work was too much.

So I opted for overloading the endpoint and using the spring boot trick to have the signature dictated by the request params.

Like so:

```
@GetMapping(params = {"foo"})
    public CollectionResource<FooResource> get(@RequestParam("foo") String foo, ...) {} ...

@GetMapping(params = {"bobby"})
    public CollectionResource<FooResource> get(@RequestParam("bobby") {} ...
```

This works well when interacting with the endpoints like so:

> localhost:8080/testEndpoint?foo=bar
>
> localhost:8080/testEndpoint?bobby=tables

However I discovered an edge case when trying the following:

> localhost:8080/testEndpoint?bobby=tables&foo=bar

Which throws the following runtime exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/testEndpoint/':
```

This endpoint is not hit by users but programmatically, so its very low chance this case would happen. However is there a way to setup the controller so it can handle this and just throw a BadRequest etc. instead of blowing up?

**Spring Boot Version** : `1.5.16.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not choose a primary endpoint?

For the first, just add the additional parameter to it

```
 public CollectionResource<FooResource> get(@RequestParam("foo") String foo, ...
  ,@RequestParam("bobby")) {
```

By that first endpoint will be chosen in this corner case

Answer (score 1):

Spring can not distinguish the endpoints on the basis of Request param.

Instead of two endpoint for serving two Request Param, have only one end point with two Request params. You have the options of making it not required.

```
@RequestParam("foo") String foo required = false, @RequestParam("bobby") String foo required = false
```

This gives you more simpler way to handle the API

Answer (score 0):

try with exception handlers

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Server Error", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: This seems dangerous, won't this mask all 500 errors, regardless of their root cause?

Comment: you have to log all error and add fix if required..its not good to throw service undefined exceptions ...